# Tree traversal BFS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a list of elements in a folder structure:

- /folder/myfile.pdf
- /folder/subfolder1/myfile.pdf
- /folder/subfolder2/myfile.pdf
- /folder/subfolder3/another/myfile.pdf

My goal is to get traverse the structure in order to build an array of files that match my filename, but where the first occurance of the item in the array would be the one closest to the root of the folder.

I was told of breadth-first traversal, but I'm getting confused.

I started taking this approach, but the result doesn't satisfy my need... I would appreciate any assistance!

```
NSMutableArray * directories = [NSMutableArray new];
NSDirectoryEnumerator *enumerator = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] enumeratorAtPath:url] retain] ;

if( [[filePath lastPathComponent] isEqualToString:@"myfile.pdf"] ){
    [directories addObject:[url stringByAppendingString:filePath]];
}

if(directories)
 sourceUrl_ = [[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[directoriesToWalk objectAtIndex:0] ] retain];
```

Comment: So you already have the list of files in an `NSArray`? Are they stored as `NSString`s or `NSURL`s?

Comment: They are as strings in the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working example of something like what you describe:

```
NSDirectoryEnumerator *enumerator = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]
                                     enumeratorAtPath:@"/Users/bdesham/Sites"];

NSMutableArray *htmlFiles = [NSMutableArray new];

NSURL *path;
while (path = [enumerator nextObject]) {
    if ([[path lastPathComponent] isEqualToString:@"index.html"]) {
        [htmlFiles addObject:@{ @"level" : [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[enumerator level]],
                                @"path" : path }];
    }
}

[htmlFiles sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    return [obj1[@"level"] integerValue] > [obj2[@"level"] integerValue];
}];

NSMutableArray *paths = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[htmlFiles count]];

[htmlFiles enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    [paths addObject:obj[@"path"]];
}];
```

The idea here is as follows:

1. Enumerate all of the files within the folder of interest.
2. For each file that has the filename you want, add it to the `htmlFiles` array. The file is added as a dictionary so that we can store the depth (the result of calling `-[NSDirectoryEnumerator level]`) along with each filename.
3. We now have an array containing all of the files in which we might be interested.
4. Sort the array according to the files’ depths (the `@"level"` key in the dictionary).
5. We don’t need the pathnames in dictionaries anymore, so create a new array containing just the pathnames (but in the same sorted order as before).

At the end of this piece of code, the `paths` array contains the `NSURL`s of all files named “index.html”, with the files closest to the root first and those furthest from the root last. (Note that the ordering within the array of two files at the same directory level is undefined.)